Variational autoencoders - handcrafted example
In learning about variational autoencoders (VAEs), I would like to come up with a nice little handcrafted example to help make sense of them thoroughly. For this, suppose I know that my samples are drawn from a five-dimensional Gaussian $\mathbf{X}=(X_1,\dots,X_5)$ in which $X_2\sim\mathcal{N}(1,1)$ and $X_5\sim\mathcal{N}(-1,4)$ are independent and $X_1=X_2$, $X_3=X_5$ and $X_4=X_2+X_5$. Suppose further that our soon to be learned VAE has a latent dimension of two. In that case (correct me if I am wrong), I would expect that the latent space $\mathbf{Z}$ is effectively just the two-dimensional Gaussian $(X_2,X_5)$ as all other random variables in the observed data depend entirely on these two and they are independent.
$\textbf{Question(s) (1):}$ Am I correct in thinking that given some sample $\mathbf{x}=(x_2,x_5)$ we would ideally have that $\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{x}$ is just $(x_2,x_5)$ itself? As in, would a well-learned encoder yield something which when sampled from yields samples very close to $(x_2,x_5)$?
I'm unsure as I think that $\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{x}$ should be a distribution and to 'guarantee' the output $(x_2,x_5)$ we would perhaps require something like $p(\mathbf{z}|\mathbf{x})=\delta(z_1-x_2)\delta(z_2-x_5)$ where $\delta$ is the dirac delta function. I'm a bit miffy on the rigorous details here, so help is appreciated.
$\textbf{Question (2):}$ In practice, I understand that $\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{x}$ is approximated by some normal distribution whose parameters are output by some neural network (the encoder). I suppose in this case it'd make sense for a 'good' encoder to output the parameters of a normal distribution whose mean is centred at $(x_2,x_5)$ and covariance matrix is diagonal with relatively small diagonal elements (say $0.01$ or so). Is this intuition correct and in line with what would would expect the learned encoder to do in practice?
$\textbf{Note:}$ on my screen my "\mathcal{N}"s for the normal distribution are appearing as square boxes. If the same applies to you, the reader, know that each square box is really the usual "N" symbol pertaining to a normal distribution.

Your math display issues are addressed in this answer. https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/385789/320588

It is true that VAEs learn a posterior distribution, but one cannot expect it to learn the actual construction in the vanilla setting. However, maybe because of your input structure, it's more likely that it learns a posterior dist that is like $P(X_2|X)P(X_5|X)$, but it could also learn a dsitribution that is like $P(X_2+X_5|X)P(X2-X_5|X))$?

VAE unlike AE does not aim to deterministically map every observed point to its corresponding latent value, instead its encoder only learns an approximate distribution of the latent variables $\mathbf{Z}$ given the data, which means that the variational posterior $p(\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{x})$ is not a Dirac delta function but rather a distribution that is typically assumed to be Gaussian, especially for continuous input data such as a set of images as well verified empirically.
Therefore in practice the VAE encoders' output will not exactly match $(x_2,x_5)$ deterministically even with one input data as you specified and its ELBO's stable training and convergence via SGD and reparameterization-trick is assumed, but will instead sample from a Gaussian distribution with small variance centered at $(x_2,x_5)$, due to various (inevitable) numerical errors when optimizing ELBO.
Finally generative VAEs usually need sufficient diversity in the input data to learn a meaningful latent space distribution via mini-batch SGD. Your model overfits with only one input.

Thank you for confirming my suspicions. Could you elaborate on your final statement regarding overfitting with only one input? Would this be alleviated by instead feeding the model the same data but with some normally distributed noise sprinkled in during training?

@smoking_big_ole_doinks adding noise to the single input alleviates overfit, and via the implicit denoising process it generalizes a bit. But it doesn't make sense to fit VAE to a single data point or with noise added, you'd better train a deterministic AE instead. Also bear in mind, as I've mentioned in my above answer that your hypothetical result only is possible with several assumptions, not necessary in itself. VAE encoder may possibly learn a 2D latent space spanned by any (linear) combination of $x_2,x5$ if such output optimizes the ELBO which cannot be ruled out. Hope this clarifies.
